# Chrome does not include a window.open("","_self") in the history list

Tags: javascript, window.open

The Javascript function below replaces the content of the current window with some new text and also adds a button to enable the user to go back to the previous content. This works in FF and IE, but not in Chrome, which apparently does not add the new-content-page to the history list. (The same behavior is shown when one uses the browser's back button).

```
function birtaSkyr(newText){
    w = window.open("", "_self","","");
    w.document.write("<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>");
    w.document.write(newText);
    w.document.write("<p /><button onclick='javascript:window.history.back();return false;'>Close</button>");
    w.document.write("</body></html>");
    w.stop();
}
```

The last of the four arguments to the window.open() function is a Boolean variable which is supposed to control whether the new page is added to the history list, but it seems to be ignored by the tree browsers I have tested.

Does anyone know how to force Chrome to include the page in the history list?

Answer (score 6):

You should include `copyhistory=yes` inside the method definition `window.open`.